# If method returns interface type, why can't I pass the result to a concrete type?

Tags: c#, interface, concrete

The question maybe a little confusing, but it's hard to make clear this question in a subject title.

I have method declared and implemented like this:

```
public IList<string> GetBookTitles()
{
    IList<string> bookTitles = new List<string>();
    // do something to populate the bookTitles list.
    return bookTitles;
}
```

Why can't I pass the result of this method to a `List<string>`?  After all, `List<string>` is a kind of `IList<string>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: **Please stop breaking your formatting**.

Comment: I don't understand the two downvotes! Perfectly good question for someone who doesn't understand the concept, if you ask me.

Comment: They just do it arbitrarily. After all, there are so many people on this planet. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, just look at the members of `IList` and compare it with `List`.  `List` has methods that an `IList` doesn't.  (`List` has a `BinarySearch` method that `IList` doesn't, just as a single example.)

Arrays also implement `IList`, as an example.  An array however is not a `List`, so you can't, and shouldn't, be able to pass a `string[]` to a method that accepts a `List<string>`.

You have a few possible solutions.  One would be to just change your method to return a `List<string>` rather than an `IList<string>` (that's what I'd suggest).  If that's what you really need then you shouldn't be restricting the return type to `IList<string>`.  Another (poorer) option would be to cast the result back to a `List<string>` before passing it to the next method, since you happen to know that it's what the underlying type really is.

Comment: I think I kinda understand it now: List<T> is only one type of IList<T>. Same is true with Dictionary<T> and IDictionary<T>.  But, why, in terms of best practice, should a method return an Interface type if the principle is to let a method return the most specific type but instead take the most general?

Comment: @Stack0verflow If you can pass an interface and have it provide all of the functionality that the caller needs, then you can pass back an interface.  If the caller needs access to functionality not provided in the interface then you shouldn't pass back the interface; you should pass back the concrete class.

Comment: Thanks, but my understanding is that for best practice, a method should return an interface type. So I had thought that "IList<string> bookTitles = new List<string>(); ...; return bookTitles;" is of better practice than "List<string> bookTitles = new List<string>(); ...; return bookTitles;".  Not true?

Comment: @Stack0verflow That is not true.  There are certainly many cases where it's appropriate to return an interface, but clearly this isn't one of them, and saying it's always best is most certainly wrong.

Comment: But it is true to let a method take the most general type (not the object type of course) . So, it is better to have MyMethod(IEnumerable<string> myCollection> than MyMethod(List<string> myCollection). Correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Stack0verflow If you only need the functionality of an `IEnumerable` in that case (for example, if you only `foreach` over it and don't do anything else with it), then that's what you should accept.  If the contents of that method relies on the parameter being a `List` (possibly because you wish to add items to the collection) then it would need to be a `List`.

Comment: I get the idea: If all functionalities we need in the method are available from IEnumerable<T>, then use IEnumerable<T> instead of List<T>, despite the fact that List<T> also has those functionalities simply because IEnumberable<T> is much more general than List<T>. I guess I am correct.

Comment: @Stack0verflow That's partly it, yes.  In the case of a method parameter by using an interface that meets your need you make it "easier" to call your method.  Someone could use a `List`, an `Array`, a `Dictionary` or any other collection that implements `IEnumerable` (most all do).  They don't need to convert their `Array` to a `List` just to call the method.  For return type that isn't relevant.  For return types it's often because you want to "hide" access to something.  You are actively trying to restrict what the caller can do with the result.

Comment: @Stack0verflow Another reason to return an interface is that the method will actually have several different concrete types returned, all of which implement some common interface.  If you want to be able to return several concrete types you obviously can't just pick one to return; it's a case where interfaces can be helpful.

Comment: So, it really doesn't make much sense to do this: "IList<string> bookTitles = new List<string>(); ... ... ; return bookTitles;"  Because the method instantiates a concrete type List<string>, but returns a more general IList<string>. I think I need to stop this practice, it looks wrong to me now.

Comment: Can anybody confirm if it is wrong to instantiate a more specific object, but return as if it is more general like below? IList<string> bookTitles = new List<string>(); ... ... ; return bookTitles;

Comment: @Stack0verflow You shouldn't just do it by default.  There should generally be some reason that you are intentionally obscuring the functionality.  In that case, you're actually obscuring functionality that you need, so it's actively harmful, not helpful.  If you didn't need the functionality you were removing then it wouldn't make all that much of a difference.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Just have to actively keep thinking about functional while programming.

Answer (score 1):

> After all, `List<string>` is a kind of `IList<string>`.

But there are also other kinds of `IList<String>`.

What if your method were to return an `IList<String>` which is a `ReadOnlyCollection<String>` instead?

```
IList<string> x = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>();
List<string> y = x;  //Huh?
```

Comment: Thank you. Please give an example to show that passing the result to List<string> will have a problem. I need a hint to think through this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler uses the signature of your methods, not the implementation when deciding if you can assign the result of GetBookTitles to your variable, so it can't know that the result will in fact be a List. If it would allow you to do such a thing, then you could write something like this:

```
List<string> myBooks = GetBookTitles();
myBooks.Sort();
```

In your example you could do this, and in fact you can if you cast the result of your method:

```
List<string> myBooks = (List<string>)GetBookTitles();
```

But then one day you could decide that your book collection is not modifiable, and you rewrite your method as follows:

```
public IList<string> GetBookTitles()
    {
        IList<string> tmp = new List<string>();
        // do something to populate the bookTitles list.
        IList<string> bookTitles = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(tmp);
        return bookTitles;
    }
```

ReadOnlyCollection does not implement Sort, so your app would compile, but would crash at runtime.
Using the cast approach it would crash when trying to do the cast, but in this case you are taking the responsibility of deciding that that kind of cast is feasible and do not have the compiler trying to guess.

A better approach could be to use as instead of the cast and chek for null. I.e.:

```
List<string> myBooks = GetBookTitles() as List<string>;
if (myBooks != null)
    myBooks.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, you just need an explicit conversion.

```
List<string> foo = (List<string>)GetBookTitles()
```

should do it.

Comment: I understand that, but I am wondering why I can't directly pass the result to a List of string.  Why do I even need the cast? Thank you!

Comment: You need the cast because an IList<string> could be any other type of IList, many of which have different methods available. Interfaces are used to add abstraction, if you don't want the abstraction, then you shouldn't use the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The interface may be implemented in various classes which are not same. So, it will be difficult to find the respective class.

You can type cast from IList to List!!!